# Regex validation returns false on Samsung Tizen TV

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I am developing a SmartTV web app using JavaScript.
I want to write a regular expression which validate the local mobile operator codes:

```
op_codes = [33, 50, 63, 66, 67, 68, 73, 93, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

My code works as it should in Chrome and LG webOS. But in Samsung Tizen **RegExp.test** returns false even though it should be true.

**Code sample:**

```
var val = '0985739341',
    op_codes = [33, 50, 63, 66, 67, 68, 73, 93, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99],
    pattern = new RegExp('^0'+'('+op_codes.join('|')+')'+'\\d{7}$');

console.log(pattern.test(val)); //Samsung Tizen output: false
```

**Here is the screenshot of Tizen console:**

[Tizen console(Updated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spjaq.png)

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code, how can I solve it?

Same code executed on Chrome and Tizen:
[Tizen(left) Chrome(right) console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hFvV.png)

**Same variable Chrome and Tizen:**

[How it can be?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4eWN.png)

Comment: The screenshot was updated, the `val` value in the console

Comment: Truly bizarre...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### New Answer

Your latest screenshot ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4eWN.png)) tells us that you have an invisible character in `val`. I really, really, really should have thought of that earlier. Apparently for whatever reason, whatever your source is for `val`, it's including an invisible character in it.

You'll need to identify it and, ideally, figure out where it comes from and fix it; otherwise, strip it out.

To figure out what it is, try this:

```
console.log("val", val);
Array.prototype.forEach.call(val, function(ch) {
    console.log(ch.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
});
```

If it were the value it *seems* to be, you'd get

```
val 0985739341
30 39 38 35 37 33 39 33 34 31
```

Live Copy:

```js
var val = "0985739341";
console.log("val", val);
console.log(Array.prototype.map.call(val, function(ch) {
    return ch.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
}).join(" "));
```

...but I bet you get something else. It could be any of several invisible characters — a zero-width space ([U+200B](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=200B)), a zero-width non-joiner ([U+200C](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=200C)), etc. Here's an example with both of those:

```js
var val = "0985\u200C\u200B739341";
console.log("val", val);
console.log(Array.prototype.map.call(val, function(ch) {
    return ch.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
}).join(" "));
```

Once you know what it is, you can find out where it comes from and get rid of it (or strip it from the string afterward).

### Old, Probably-Incorrect Answer

> I can't figure out what is wrong with my code...

If that screenshot is genuine, then there's nothing wrong with your code; there's a bug in the JavaScript engine being used on that device. This would appear to be one of the rare cases where the rule ["`select` isn't broken"](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips) fails. (Would *appear* to be, keep being skeptical and keep double-checking yourself.)

You'll have to experiment to see *where* it fails (and file an appropriate bug report) and work around it. For instance, maybe the implementation of `test` incorrectly ignores capture groups and so isn't applying `|` correctly, or `new RegExp` is just fundamentally broken, or... It'll take a lot of experimentation to figure it out.

Below are your original validation (`validate1`) and three alternatives you might try. The second (`validate2`) uses a non-capturing group instead of a capturing group. They *should* be the same as far as `test` is concerned, but then again, your original code should work. :-)

```js
var val = '0985739341';
var op_codes = [33, 50, 63, 66, 67, 68, 73, 93, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99];
var val1PatternStr = '^0'+'('+op_codes.join('|')+')'+'\\d{7}$';
var val1Pattern = new RegExp(val1PatternStr);
var val2PatternStr = '^0'+'(?:'+op_codes.join('|')+')'+'\\d{7}$';
var val2Pattern = new RegExp(val2PatternStr);

console.log(1, validate1(val));
console.log(2, validate2(val));
console.log(3, validate3(val));
console.log(4, validate4(val));
    
function validate1(val) {
    return val1Pattern.test(val);
}

function validate2(val) {
    return val2Pattern.test(val);
}

function validate3(val) {
    return val.length === 10 &&
           val[0] == "0" &&
           op_codes.indexOf(+val.substring(1,3)) != -1 &&
           /^\d+$/.test(val.substring(3));
}

function validate4(val) {
    return val.length === 10 &&
           val[0] == "0" &&
           op_codes.indexOf(+val.substring(1,3)) != -1 &&
           sillyIsDigit(val[3]) &&
           sillyIsDigit(val[4]) &&
           sillyIsDigit(val[5]) &&
           sillyIsDigit(val[6]) &&
           sillyIsDigit(val[7]) &&
           sillyIsDigit(val[8]) &&
           sillyIsDigit(val[9]);
}

function sillyIsDigit(ch) {
    return ch >= "0" && ch <= "9";
}
```

If the JavaScript engine chokes on `val[0]`, you'll have to change all of those `[]` on `val` to calls to `charAt` instead: `val[0]` => `val.charAt(0)`.

Comment: Thx, everything working fine(Look at the Tizen console screenshot in my question). I'll try to test this bug and find where it appears.

Comment: @La_Concorde Glad it's working! But I'm confused by the latest screenshot. Why the `\\` between `^` and `0`? And my `validate1` is the same as your original code, I don't see why it would suddenly magically work...?

Comment: Precisely, early was overjoyed it is not working with your solutions. My typo mislead me.)) 
I was add new screenshot with the same code was executed in Chrome and Tizen.I'm even more confused than before.

Comment: can you explain me the output showed on the third screenshot in my answer? I am really confused.

Comment: @La_Concorde: Yes: An invisible character. I've updated the answer. :-)

Comment: http://joxi.ru/vAWR0OeI1Zjap2 Look at this screenshot, please, my invisible character is `d`. Tell me please why I do not see this character in console in browser? How can I avoid it?

Comment: @La_Concorde: To my surprise, the console just doesn't show carriage returns (that's what that character is, `\r`). I can't tell you how to avoid it, something is inserting those carriage returns between the digits. You can easily remove them (`val = val.replace(/\r/g, "");` but if I were you I'd find out what's inserting them in the first place.

Comment: Thx, this fixed my problem. I will follow your advice and I'll look where it comes from.